# Horizontal scroll flexbox: Child image exceeds height of parent instead of filling up height

Tags: css, flexbox, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to make a horizontal scrollable image gallery with `flexbox`, but I am unable to make the image height grow to fill up the container height while also keeping a fixed aspect ratio.

The amount of cards can be variable, so it should be some flexible code that fills up the space and has a horizontal scroll if there are enough tiles.

[image]

Here is a simplified version of the issue (check out the full page for better result):

```css
body,ul{
margin:0; padding:0;
}

ul.hor-bar{
 background:pink;
 border:1rem solid crimson;
 padding:2rem;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 
 display: flex;
 gap: 2rem;
 height:100vh;
 max-height: 100%;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}

li.card{
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  //flex-shrink: 0; 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

p{
  flex:auto;

  /*extra style*/
  background: magenta;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.img-container{
  height:100%;
  flex:1 ;
  width:auto;
  max-height: 100%; /* <=required */
}

img{
 height:100%;
 width:auto;  /* <=required => or 100% with flex-shrink: 0 */
 object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hor-bar">
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

I know in this previous example removing the height of 100vh fixes the issue. But I am searching for a solution that uses a dynamic height. Here is another example which does not use the 100vh.

```css
body,ul{
margin:0; padding:0;

}

.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  padding-top:4rem;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  background: green;
}

ul.hor-bar{
 background:pink;
 border:1rem solid crimson;
 padding:2rem;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 
 display: flex;
 gap: 2rem;
 height:100%;
 
 overflow-x: scroll;
}

li.card{
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  //flex-shrink: 0; 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

p{
  flex:auto;

  /*extra style*/
  background: magenta;
  padding: 4vh 0;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.img-container{
  height:100%;
  flex:1 ;
  width:auto;
  max-height: 100%; /* <=required */
}

img{
 height:100%;
 width:auto;  /* <=required => or 100% with flex-shrink: 0 */
 object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
<ul class="hor-bar">
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bCBt6ga.jpeg" alt="pepe">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
 </ul>
 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something needs to define the height of the scroll area.  Every child needs to have its height be defined as something other than auto.  Then you can set the `<img>` height to 100% of its container.  If you don't otherwise specify the width of the element, it will be auto, and therefore retain its natural aspect ratio.

Demo below with images of different sizes and aspect ratios.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.hor-bar {
  background: pink;
  border: 1rem solid crimson;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 85% 15%;
}

.img-container {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  background: magenta;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hor-bar">
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/600/900" alt="dog">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/600" alt="laptop">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/63/700/600" alt="coffee">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/70/900" alt="trees">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/112/800/500" alt="wheat">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/168/200/300" alt="rocks">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/210/800/300" alt="bricks">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
    </li>
   <li class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/216/500/800" alt="path">
    </div>
    <p>Card text</p>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At the moment I had kind of the same solution by just add a fixed height of `90%` to the `image-container`. But this is very depended on the amount of characters used under the picture, and so it doesn't feel very flexible.